# DropDown change show partial

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have used from dropdownlist in page.

I want, when change selected id info, load bottom of page.
first time that page load is true,but with dropdown change load info in new page, not  part of current page.

**Fill dropdown list**

```
public ActionResult selVahedList(int IdType, int IdChoose)
{
    ViewBag.ChooseItem = IdChoose;
    IEnumerable<Lcity> Lcitys = Dbcon.Lcitys;
    var model = new CityViewMode
    {
        Lcitys = Lcitys.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = x.Citycode.ToString(),
            Text = x.CityName
        })
    };
    return View(model);
});
```

**Partial view shows after dropdown changed**

```
 public ActionResult selVahedListAjax(CityViewMode model)
    {
        int idcity=Convert.ToInt32(model.SelectedCitycode);
       // int idcity = 1;
        ViewBag.Reshteh = 1;
        //string IdCity = base.Request["SelValue"].ToString();
        var res = Dbcon.TaavoniInfos.Where(m => m.IDReshteh == 1 && m.Citycode ==idcity);
        return PartialView("selVahedListAjax", res);
    }
```

**view page**

```
    AjaxOptions ajaxOpts = new AjaxOptions
      {
       UpdateTargetId = "LoadData",
       LoadingElementId="loadAdmin"
      };
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("selVahedListAjax",ajaxOpts))

{
    <fieldset>
<div class="PContent">
<p class="DroplistCity" id="DroplistCity">

        @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.SelectedCitycode,
        new SelectList(Model.Lcitys, "Value", "Text",""))

       <div id="LoadData">
        @Html.Action("selVahedListAjax", new { IdReshte = ViewBag.ChooseItem })
    </div>

    </div>
    </fieldset>
    }
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#SelectedCitycode').change(function () {
                this.form.submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

thanks for your help

```
my partial view code is:                                            @model 

IEnumerable<TaavonS.Models.TaavoniInfo>

    <ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model) 
    {
          <li>:<b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SName)</b></li>
      <li>:<b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ModirName)</b></li>
      <li><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/list16.png")" alt=""/>
      @Html.ActionLink("detail....", "Detaild",new { codef= item.Scode }, new { @class = "openDialog", data_dialog_id = "emailDialog", data_dialog_title = "" } ) 
      <hr class="separatorLine"/></li> when i load page is true but after dropdownlist is nt work 


     <li>
      @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.TablighatPic))
      { 
      <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/eye.png")"/> @Html.ActionLink("تبلیغات....", "showImg", new { code = item.Scode }, new { @class = "openImg", data_dialog_id = "mailDialog" })<hr class="separatorLine"/>
      }
     </li>
    }
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your ajaxOptions:

```
AjaxOptions ajaxOpts = new AjaxOptions
  {
   UpdateTargetId = "LoadData",
   LoadingElementId="loadAdmin",
   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace // add this line
  };
```

Add the parameter to the beginForm call

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("selVahedListAjax",
        new { IdReshte = ViewBag.ChooseItem }, //add this to the Ajax.BeginForm call
        ajaxOpts ))

{
```

and remove this line from the target div if you don't want the ajax call performed before the user chooses anything

```
@Html.Action("selVahedListAjax", new { IdReshte = ViewBag.ChooseItem })
```

Comment: thank u for your help i put insertionmode but didnt solve my problem

Comment: Forgot to mention that you have to move the things you want displayed in the LoadData div to another partial view or else, the whole page is being reinserted in the target div